# Pytest call a class method from teardown fixture

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

My class the handles the setup and teardown is like below

```
@dataclass
class DeployStack:
    stack: Stack
    stack_path: Path
    template_test: bool = False
    integration_test: bool = False

    """ it supports either template or integration tests"""

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not self.template_test and not self.integration_test:
            raise ValueError("template_test or integration_test must be provided")
        if not self.stack and not self.stack_path:
            raise ValueError("stack or stack_path must be provided")

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            """ do some setup """
            func(*args,**kwargs)

        return wrapper

    def cleanup(self):
        if self.integration_test:
            """ Do some cleanup """
```

My `fixture` is like below

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def deploy_stack():
    yield DeployStack
    """cleanup after the test"""
    DeployStack.cleanup()
```

And the `testcase` is something like

```
def test_deploy_stack(deploy_stack):
    @deploy_stack(stack=sqs_stack, stack_path=cdk_app_path, integration_test=True)
    def test_deploy_stack(template, stack, completed_process_for_deployment):
        assert completed_process_for_deployment.returncode == 0
        assert stack

    test_deploy_stack()
```

Now I am having couple of issues here

1. The teardown/cleanup is not working because of `object instantiation` issue
2. What is the elegant way of write multiple `testcases` but `DeployStack` and `cleaup` getting called only once.